# SwiftUI: Inline image size

Tags: swiftui

I am adding inline image (SF symbol) into Text with `.appendInterpolation` like this:

```
Text("Hello \(Image(systemName: "swift"))")
```

This works great, but I would like to change the symbol size. How can I do it?

I tried

```
Text("Hello \(Image(systemName: "swift").font(.system(size: 12)))")
```

but I only get this error: `'appendInterpolation' is unavailable: Unsupported type for interpolation, see LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation for supported types.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How about using `plus operator` for `Text`?

```swift
Text("Hello ")
+
Text(Image(systemName: "swift"))
    .font(.title.bold())
+
Text(" Swift!")
```

Comment: Thank you! This syntax is a bit hard to intuit, this is what I needed.